# Running my application in a Docker Container

Tags: docker

I am working on one of my organization project where we have an embedded device named Gateway through which we are able to read electricity meters over DLMS and Modbus protocol. Gateway is able to read meters over these protocols and interpret the received data and send it to backoffice in a homogeneous JSON data structure over secure websocket transport layer protocol using SIM or Ethernet. Gateway Application OS is having our custom linux, application code is written in .NET C# and running on Linux using Mono Framework. This application is having 6 binaries, 4 SQLite db, some dlls and some shared C libraries. This is working fine on my embedded device gateway. Now some of customers do not want the embedded device Gateway but want a solution that run on windows PC which can read meters over TCP and able to send data to backoffice over Ethernet and save it in proper database. Now to serve this requirement we have 2 approaches: -

1. Develop an entire new .NET application on Windows OS which do the same purpose.
2. Dockerize the entire gateway application in a docker container and run it on the Windows OS using Docker Desktop.

We are thinking in the direction of 2nd approach because we have to maintain only one code base for both the solutions. But our organization is not very much expertise in Docker.

Please suggest that whether our thinking is correct or not. We should go with the 2nd approach or with the 1st approach where we have to develop an entire new codebase for that.

Comment: Docker is designed to host single binary. I would suggest to setup virtual machine which runs full-blown linux server without GUI. This way your environment will be very close to gateway device and customization costs would be near zero.

Answer (score 1):

Well, its hard to suggest anything because the application is not trivial.

However, what I can say is that the cost of developing a new application for windows and in perspective maintaining two version is pretty high.

On the other hand, trying to run a dockerized version of the existing application should be pretty low (well at least much lower than the first path), after all you should create a Dockerfile with all the required customizations and build the image. From that point you can merely run the process out of that image.

So IMHO you should try that option first and get to conclusions whether its a viable solution in your case pretty soon. In the worst case you'll get to the first solution at the end but the overhead is pretty low.

One thing that you should know that usually Docker works best if you have a single process dockerized, and you're running 6 as you said. You might need something like `supervisor.d` to run them all: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/

Answer (score 0):

to answer a question, I would want to know why they want to do this.
It would be normal for a gateway to be a field mounted device that connects to meters using one physical protocol layer, and to then either provide pass through of meter data to a scada or head end system using a back haul, normally ip based. (More complex gateways may provide a level of virtualisation of the meters, And I think this may be the case here). If the meters can already operate on tcp, then there should normally be no need for a gateway.  So, it seems that your client maybe wants to use the gateway code as a poor mans scada system or head end system. 
If you can explain the architecture of the end to end solution, it may allow an understanding of the need to try to virtualise the gateway device, and this may well be key to determining the best approach.